# sql query for counting the records of particular id and show in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a following table:-

```
declare @tab table(name varchar(10),id int)

insert into @tab values ('A',1),('B',1),('C',1),('D',1),('E',2),('F',2)
```

I need following output:-

```
declare @tab1 table(name varchar(10),id int, cnt int)

insert into @tab1 values ('A',1,4),('B',1,4),('C',1,4),('D',1,4),('E',2,2),('F',2,2)
select * from @tab1
```

I tried following query:-

```
select name,id,count(*) as cnt
from @tab 
group by name,id
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove sql-server-2012 tag, because it's no longer supported. Also, very unclear question. What do you want, what do you get with the code you've tried? Please, edit

Comment: If the OP is using SQL Server 2012 removing that tag makes little sense, @Ineffable21 ; in fact it's important for us to know that the OP is using *completely unsupported* technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select name
     , id
     , count(*) over(partition by id) as cnt
from @tab
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Done

```
;with a as
(
select Id,name, count(*) over (partition by id) cnt

from @tab
)
select Id,name,cnt
from a
```